# как сделать автоматическую замену нерабочего прокси? xNet

Tags: c#, xnet

собственно вопрос в названии темы. есть код, который отправляет запрос используя прокси и прописаны исключения в случае ошибки, а так же есть текстовый файл который содержит запасные прокси, в случае, если используемый прокси окажется не рабочим. вопрос, как мне загружать новый прокси и автоматически снова отправлять запрос, в случае, если нынешний окажется не рабочим?
вот код:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse("183.207.228.7:8000");
                var request = new HttpRequest();
                request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
                request.Proxy = proxyClient;
                // Отправляем запрос.
                HttpResponse response = request.Get("http://2ip.ru/");
                // Принимаем тело сообщения в виде строки.
                string content = response.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(content);
                File.WriteAllText("asd.txt", content);
                Console.Read();
            }

            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка при работе с HTTP-сервером: {0}", ex.Message);

                switch (ex.Status)
                {
                    case HttpExceptionStatus.Other:
                        Console.WriteLine("Неизвестная ошибка");Console.Read();
                        break;

                    case HttpExceptionStatus.ProtocolError:
                        Console.WriteLine("Код состояния: {0}", (int)ex.HttpStatusCode);Console.Read();
                        break;

                    case HttpExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure:
                        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось соединиться с HTTP-сервером.");Console.Read();
                        break;

                    case HttpExceptionStatus.SendFailure:
                        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось отправить запрос HTTP-серверу.");Console.Read();
                        break;

                    case HttpExceptionStatus.ReceiveFailure:
                        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось загрузить ответ от HTTP-сервера.");Console.Read();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

использую библиотеку xNet.

Comment: Что означает «загружать новый прокси»? И что такое «нерабочий прокси»?

Comment: var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse("183.207.228.7:8000"); – вот строка, которая отвечает за то, через какой проси я буду отправлять запрос. если прокси, который тут вставлен - не рабочий, как мне автоматически из файла брать новый прокси и вставлять его сюда, и автоматически отправлять новый запрос, пока не получу конечный ответ от сайта?

Comment: нерабочий прокси - прокси, через который нельзя будет подлючаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Для начала, загружаем список прокси:

```
var proxies = File.ReadLines("path/to/proxy.txt").ToList();
var goodProxyIndex = 0;
// оформьте это в класс
```

Теперь процедура с попыткой читать с прокси (может кинуть исключение):

```
string GetContent(string proxy, string address)
{
    var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse(proxy);
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
    request.Proxy = proxyClient;
    // Отправляем запрос.
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(address);
    // Принимаем тело сообщения в виде строки.
    return response.ToString();
}
```

Ну и обвязка:

```
var numProxies = proxies.Count;
for (var try = 0; try < numProxies; try++)
{
    try
    {
        return GetContent(proxies[goodProxyIndex], address);
    }
    catch (тут исключения, которые значат, что нельзя подключиться)
    {
        // прокси плохой, пробуем следующий
        goodProxyIndex = (goodProxyIndex + 1) % numProxies;
    }
}
// если мы тут, хороших прокси не осталось
throw new NoGoodProxyException();
```

Возможно, вы захотите вести статистику по proxy и удалять те, которые не срабатывают больше, скажем, 5 раз.

---

Обновление: Вот всё вместе

```
class ProxyDowloader
{
    List<string> proxies;
    int goodProxyIndex = 0;

    public ProxyDownloader(string pathToProxy)
    {
        proxies = File.ReadLines("path/to/proxy.txt").ToList();
    }

    private string GetContent(string proxy, string address)
    {
        var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse(proxy);
        var request = new HttpRequest();
        request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
        request.Proxy = proxyClient;
        // Отправляем запрос.
        HttpResponse response = request.Get(address);
        // Принимаем тело сообщения в виде строки.
        return response.ToString();
    }

    public string GetProxiedContent(string address)
    {
        var numProxies = proxies.Count;
        for (var try = 0; try < numProxies; try++)
        {
            try
            {
                return GetContent(proxies[goodProxyIndex], address);
            }
            catch (тут исключения, которые значат, что нельзя подключиться)
            {
                // прокси плохой, пробуем следующий
                goodProxyIndex = (goodProxyIndex + 1) % numProxies;
            }
        }
        // если мы тут, хороших прокси не осталось
        throw new NoGoodProxyException();
    }
}
```

Пользуемся:

```
var dl = new ProxyDowloader("path/to/proxylist");
try
{
    var content = dl.GetProxiedContent("http://2ip.ru");
    File.WriteAllText("some.file.txt", content);
}
catch
{
    // что-то сказать пользователю
}
Console.Read(); // если вам уж так хочется
```

Comment: @inkorpus: Должно быть легко. Если не будет что-то выходить, переспрашивайте.

Comment: http://cs623622.vk.me/v623622064/27770/2z3gdr5CW48.jpg – ну вот так вот я переписал ваш код, из файла берётся только 1ый прокси. если он правильный, то считывание происходит как надо, если не правильный, то на следующий прокси не переходит. что нужно исправить?

Comment: @inkorpus: А зачем вы повставляли `Console.Read` во внутренние функции? Вы убрали `return GetContent(proxies[goodProxyIndex], address);`, а он был важен, так как выходил из цикла. Сделайте из обвязочного кода отдельную функцию, не ленитесь :-)

Comment: как из этого сделать отдельную функцию?) я этого не поинмаю

Comment: @inkorpus: Сейчас добавлю в ответ

Comment: благодарю Вас!!

Comment: @inkorpus: Написал

Comment: если честно то ошибки есть в синтаксисе, спасибо вам большое за помощь!!) я уже завтра разбирать буду, напишу сюда, в случае чего

Comment: с вами нельзя связаться в скайпе или через teamviewer? так намного быстрее будет) в методе GetProxiedContent не все ветви кода возвращают значение.

Comment: @inkorpus: к сожалению, связаться не получится :-( А вы не выкинули случайно исключение в конце метода?

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c623622/v623622064/2780b/57ICKxGCvBU.jpg , https://pp.vk.me/c623622/v623622064/27814/bjU-uHptFOc.jpg – вот что я имею) как эти ошибки исправить?)

Comment: @inkorpus: Ну ёлки, скопируйте же без ошибок. Где у вас класс `class ProxyDowloader`?

Comment: http://cs623225.vk.me/v623225064/2d5ef/oHJlLMumoHE.jpg , http://cs623225.vk.me/v623225064/2d5f8/aFyGctBhr3E.jpg – добавил в виде класса, 2 ошибки..) 
с вами даже в соц сетях не получится списатсья?(вк, одноклассники), я просто не хочу тратить ваше время на это) соц сети ускорят процесс

Comment: @inkorpus: Ну посмотрите, у вас неправильно скопирован конструктор. И вы закомментировали исключение в конце метода.

Comment: http://cs623225.vk.me/v623225064/2d60a/tFAGgj1jSZ8.jpg , http://cs623225.vk.me/v623225064/2d61a/IhRXh7j8wdY.jpg - ошибок нет, но и считывания тоже)

Comment: @inkorpus: Попробуйте оттрассировать. Может, оно не находит proxy.txt? Бросается ли исключение? Выведите что-нибудь в catch-блоке.

Comment: а метод "ProxyDownloader" какого типа должен быть? вы когда пример писали то не указали там тип, я поставил у себя void

Comment: я думаю что сам прокси не передаётся просто, вопрос - почему?

Comment: @inkorpus: Это ж не метод, это конструктор!

Comment: @inkorpus: Аааааааа! Вы сделали из него метод! Верните как было!

Comment: http://cs623225.vk.me/v623225064/2d641/oe9wh-cEEKk.jpg - вот так сделал, открывается консоль и секунд 5 висит, потом закрывается, создаётся текстовый файл в который должен сохраняться результат, но там ничего нет

Comment: @inkorpus: может, положите весь текст на pastebin? Так проще, чем картинки.

Comment: сейчас рабочий прокси был последний в файле и ответ пришёл) но если рабочий прокси будет на 1 месте, а после него не рабочие прокси, то он возьмёт рабочий, и не останавливаясь возьмёт следующий. а что делать, если мне не надо чтоб он брал следующий?

Comment: @inkorpus: по идее, если прокси рабочий, продвижения к следующему не будет

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/FGVQThmH вот, смотрите

Comment: @inkorpus: Ну, вы зачем-то закомментировали список прокси и конструктор (в классе `ProxyDowloader`). Верните!

Comment: нет, всё правильно сделано) сейчас ещё закинул свежий прокси перед нерабочими, программа использовала его и считала страницу, затем поместил свежий  прокси в конец и программа снова считала страницу, всё работает, спасибо вам большое!) скажите, а ваши контакты никак нельзя получить, если совет нужен будет? вы же не всегда тут можете быть)

Comment: @inkorpus: Когда я в настроении помочь — я всегда здесь. (Это довольно часто.)

Comment: @inkorpus: Сейчас неправильно вот что: список прокси перечитывается каждый раз при вызове `GetProxiedContent`, это потенциально не очень хорошо. Лучше делать это в конструкторе, а имя файла передавать в конструктор снаружи, а то у класса слишком много ответственности.

Comment: ну ладно, ещё раз благодарю вас!

Comment: @inkorpus: Пожалуйста!