# Обработка исключений. C#. Не все ветви кода возвращают значение

Tags: c#, исключения, прокси, try-catch

Здравствуйте! Извиняюсь, если вдруг повторюсь.
Есть метод:

```
private string GetContent(string proxy, string address)
{
     var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse(proxy);
     var request = new HttpRequest();
     request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
     request.Proxy = proxyClient;
     HttpResponse response = request.Get(address);
     return response.ToString();
}
```

А также метод, возвращающий предыдущий:

```
public string GeneralGetContent(string address)
{
     var proxies = File.ReadLines("Proxy_list.txt").ToList();
     var numProxies = proxies.Count;
     for (int t = 0;t < numProxies; t++)
     {
         try
         {
            return GetContent(proxies[goodProxyIndex], address);
         }
         catch (HttpException ex)
         {
            goodProxyIndex = (goodProxyIndex + 1) % numProxies;

         }
            throw new Exception("Не осталось хороших прокси");
     }
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:
GeneralGetContent(string): не все ветви кода возвращают значение.

Но ведь мне и не нужно, чтобы в блоке `catch` был `return`, потому что при неработающем прокси, в блоке `catch` он поменяется и будет вызван заново. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это обойти и убрать ошибку.
Код был взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415373/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-xnet)

Comment: ошибку выдает `GetProxContent` а ты привел `GeneralGetContent` и `GetContent`

Comment: Извиняюсь что ввел в заблуждение вас, ошибся. Ошибку выдает: GeneralGetContent

Comment: Так ведь у вас метод GeneralGetContent должен возвращать string, а слова return в нем ни одного( напишите в конце метода return ""; и усё

Comment: @СергейПолушин за такие советы расстреливать надо.

Comment: @СергейПолушин возвращать в конце надо не случайную строковую константу - а осмысленное значение

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, да там логика в коде отсутствует напрочь, смотреть страшно, так что хуже уже не будет

Comment: @СергейПолушин в коде есть логика. Просто одна из строчек не на своем месте. Надо всего-то поменять ее местами со следующей...

Comment: @МаксимМолчанов так у вас код из чужого ответа? Мда, вы даже скопировать код без ошибки не смогли...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, мож тогда дубликатом на тот вопрос или как опечатку закрыть?

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за ответы. Это я осознанно изменил. На ошибку не влияет никак, потому что в изначальном коде тоже самое в этом месте.

Comment: добавил минусаторов в игнор , минусов наставили потом как попугаи скопипастили ответ

Comment: @PavelMayorov Извиняюсь за невнимательность, стыдно.

Comment: @DigitalCore если что, на этом сайте нет функции игнора пользователей :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov если, что какой привет - такой ответ , если расценивать код тс. то помогать ему нужно в другом. Но вы же все здесь гуру с короной, интересно что произойдёт если  списке окажется не того типа прокси ?! это не вопрос - это утверждение.
Ответь мне на этот вопрос :https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747516/c-Как-проверить-тип-прокси-без-webrequest

Answer (score 2):

В случае, если файл `Proxy_list.txt` пустой, `proxies.Count` будет `0` и ты не войдешь в цикл.

Для этого случая у тебя нет `return`.

---

Как подсказывает [@PavelMayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747488/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-c-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/747491#comment1148857_747488) скорее всего выброс исключения должен быть **вне цикла**

```
public string GeneralGetContent(string address)
{
    ...
    for (int t = 0;t < numProxies; t++)
    {
        try{
         return ...;
        }catch(...){...}
    }

    throw new Exception("Не осталось хороших прокси");
}
```

Comment: Да, помогло! Спасибо вам большое! Извиняюсь за тупость(

Comment: @МаксимМолчанов, скорее невнимательность. Нужно быть чуть внимательнее, даже когда копируешь код из ответов.

Comment: Хорошо, стыдно очень. извиняюсь еще раз.