# C# Как проверить тип прокси, без webrequest

Tags: c#, proxy

Интересует каким образом можно средствами C# определить тип прокси: Socks4, Socks5, http, имея **адрес : порт** не используя webrequest запросов.
Если не затруднит приведите пример реализации изложенный в коде.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если не Request - остаётся чистый сокет (не Socks). Других решений нету.

Comment: Нужно на сокет отправить три (как худший случай) запроса ( Socks4-прокси приглашение, Socks5, http-приглашение), и по ответам будет понятен тип прокси (если прокся не отвалится, или не внесёт вас в черный список).

Comment: А как вы себе представляете другие решения? Кроме сокета разве есть другие пути достучатся до прокси? Если нет возможности прочесть с конфигурации тип прокси (допустим системный реестр винды)  то остаётся только коннект-тест.

Comment: Может вы имеете ввиду "как получить тип прокси из настроек винды" (реестр отпадает т.к. нужны права на ветку, есть функции которые отдают настройки)?

Comment: @DigitalCore какие вопросы у вас, может вам стоит набраться опыта, а потом использовать все в комплексе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать приконектится к известному ресурсу, используя низкоуровневые команды протокола. Примеры моего кода на гитхабе:

https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/Proxy/Socks4.cs
https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/Proxy/Socks5.cs
https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/Proxy/HttpProxy.cs

Sock5 использует специальное Greeting сообщение, которое не конектится ни к чему, таким образом определить Sock5 проще всего.

Comment: @DigitalCore я не понимаю на каком основании мне нужно приводить пример кода по первому запросу непонятно кого. А соседнюю тему надо обсуждать в соседней теме.